# kubectl port forwarding gives error even with kubectl flags

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have tried all sorts of flags but I still cannot use kubernetes port forward feature every time I use port forwarding it gives a timeout error even if I use:

`--pod-running-timeout flag`

**Screenshot of CMD**

[image]

Comment: Can you share some more details, is your pod in running status ?

Comment: The output of `kubectl get pods -n kubeapps` or even `kubectl describe thePodYouveHiddenOnYourScreenshot -n kubeapps` would help here.